How to dynamically declare attribute types for type hints?
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, StatVariable(value))
        return

stats = Stats(
    zaz=0,
    lol=33,
)

print(stats.lol) 


Maybe pass generic like this:
stats = Stats['zaz', 'lol'](
    zaz=0,
    lol=33,
)

Maybe dynamically create a new subtype and create an instance of it?
Maybe there is some property that type checkers read programmatically, and I should set new attribute names in it?

You can define Stats as a collections.namedtuple:
from collections import namedtuple

Stats = namedtuple('Stats', ['zaz', 'lol'])
stats = Stats(zaz=0, lol=33)
print(stats.lol) # outputs 33

Demo: https://ideone.com/F09StX

There's also dataclasses.make_dataclass if you want to use that instead of namedtuple https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass
